# pouchDB sync but limit the returned docs?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I use pouchdb to watch for changes at my backend (couchdb), and push newly added item into the frontend. Here's the code for sync but is there any option to limit the returned docs?

```
localDB.sync(remoteDB, {
    live: true,
    retry: true
  })
```

The problem without limit options is that I'm not able to get says first 10 or 20 record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to sync, but only for a certain number of documents, use a `change` watcher, to count, and abort when you reach your limit.

```
var count = 0,
    limit = 10;
var sync = PouchDB.sync('mydb', 'http://localhost:5984/mydb', {
  live: true,
  retry: true
}).on('change', function (info) {
  if (count++ >= limit) {
    sync.cancel();
  }
})
```

Note that this will cancel the sync after 10 *changes*, which is not the same as 10 *documents*. This could potentially be 10 changes to the same document.

If you care about actual documents, you'll need more sophisticated logic to track the number of changed documents.

Comment: ya I've changed to `changes` instead of using sync, and there's an option for `limit` in `changes`

Answer (score 0):

To be honest im not sure if sync is for your use case the correct tool.

By just syncing part of the data you will cant ensure updates to existing documents.

What you could do if you just want to get lets say the 10-20 newest datasets is to periodically query a view on your server and to save the result locally in memory/localStorage/indexedDb if you don't need to offline edit them.

If you want to edit them offline you could put them into a PouchDB with upstream sync. To 
insert them into your database while retaining the _rev, you could use PouchDBs bulkDocs Api with the option {new_edits: false}

```
db.bulkDocs([
  {
    title  : 'Lisa Says',
    artist : 'Velvet Underground',
    _id    : "doc1",
    _rev   : "1-84abc2a942007bee7cf55007cba56198"
  },
  {
    title  : 'Space Oddity',
    artist : 'David Bowie',
    _id    : "doc2",
    _rev   : "1-7b80fc50b6af7a905f368670429a757e"
  }
],
{new_edits: false}).then(function (result) {
  // handle result
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Sources:

https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_create